# grep to match pattern within a column and within the value of the column in r

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to match various key-value patterns within an AdditionalInfo column, then output the key-value pairs as separate columns in R.

My single column has values like this with key-value pairs separated by semicolons (;):

```
gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2";
```

So I would want to use grep to match "gene_id "E[*]";" then output the found pattern to a new column; use grep to match "gene_type "[Aa-Zz]";" then output the found pattern to a new column, etc.

I can't just split the column on the semicolon because some rows have 6 key-value pairs, and some have 13 key-value pairs, and they are not in the same order and they are unique values.

Can anyone help me with this?

The code I am trying to use is the following:

```
geneID <- og[grep("gene_id "E[*]";", og$AdditionalInfo),]
```

Thanks for your time!

**Edit**

My data looks like this:

```
> names(og)
[1] "Chromosome"     "AnnotSource"    "FeatureType"    "Start"          "Stop"          
[6] "Score"          "Strand"         "GenomicPhase"   "AdditionalInfo"

> head(og)
  Chromosome AnnotSource FeatureType Start  Stop Score Strand GenomicPhase
1       chr1      HAVANA        gene 11869 14409     .      +            .
2       chr1      HAVANA  transcript 11869 14409     .      +            .
3       chr1      HAVANA        exon 11869 12227     .      +            .
4       chr1      HAVANA        exon 12613 12721     .      +            .
5       chr1      HAVANA        exon 13221 14409     .      +            .
6       chr1      HAVANA  transcript 12010 13670     .      +            .

AdditionalInfo
1 gene_id ENSG00000223972.5; gene_type transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene;     gene_status KNOWN; gene_name DDX11L1; level 2; havana_gene OTTHUMG00000000961.2;
2 gene_id ENSG00000223972.5; transcript_id ENST00000456328.2; gene_type transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene; gene_status KNOWN; gene_name DDX11L1; transcript_type processed_transcript; transcript_status KNOWN; transcript_name DDX11L1-002; level 2; tag basic; transcript_support_level 1; havana_gene OTTHUMG00000000961.2; havana_transcript OTTHUMT00000362751.1;
3 gene_id ENSG00000223972.5; transcript_id ENST00000456328.2; gene_type transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene; gene_status KNOWN; gene_name DDX11L1; transcript_type processed_transcript; transcript_status KNOWN; transcript_name DDX11L1-002; exon_number 1; exon_id ENSE00002234944.1; level 2; tag basic; transcript_support_level 1; havana_gene OTTHUMG00000000961.2; havana_transcript OTTHUMT00000362751.1;
4 gene_id ENSG00000223972.5; transcript_id ENST00000456328.2; gene_type transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene; gene_status KNOWN; gene_name DDX11L1; transcript_type processed_transcript; transcript_status KNOWN; transcript_name DDX11L1-002; exon_number 2; exon_id ENSE00003582793.1; level 2; tag basic; transcript_support_level 1; havana_gene OTTHUMG00000000961.2; havana_transcript OTTHUMT00000362751.1;
5 gene_id ENSG00000223972.5; transcript_id ENST00000456328.2; gene_type transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene; gene_status KNOWN; gene_name DDX11L1; transcript_type processed_transcript; transcript_status KNOWN; transcript_name DDX11L1-002; exon_number 3; exon_id ENSE00002312635.1; level 2; tag basic; transcript_support_level 1; havana_gene OTTHUMG00000000961.2; havana_transcript OTTHUMT00000362751.1;
6 gene_id ENSG00000223972.5; transcript_id ENST00000450305.2; gene_type transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene; gene_status KNOWN; gene_name DDX11L1; transcript_type transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene; transcript_status KNOWN; transcript_name DDX11L1-001; level 2; ont PGO:0000005; ont PGO:0000019; tag basic; transcript_support_level NA; havana_gene OTTHUMG00000000961.2; havana_transcript OTTHUMT00000002844.2;

> dput(head(og))
structure(list(Chromosome = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", 
"chr1", "chr1"), AnnotSource = c("HAVANA", "HAVANA", "HAVANA", 
"HAVANA", "HAVANA", "HAVANA"), FeatureType = c("gene", "transcript", 
"exon", "exon", "exon", "transcript"), Start = c(11869L, 11869L, 
11869L, 12613L, 13221L, 12010L), Stop = c(14409L, 14409L, 12227L, 
12721L, 14409L, 13670L), Score = c(".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "."
), Strand = c("+", "+", "+", "+", "+", "+"), GenomicPhase = c(".", 
".", ".", ".", ".", "."), AdditionalInfo = c("gene_id ENSG00000223972.5; gene_type transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene; gene_status KNOWN; gene_name DDX11L1; level 2; havana_gene OTTHUMG00000000961.2;", 
"gene_id ENSG00000223972.5; transcript_id ENST00000456328.2; gene_type transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene; gene_status KNOWN; gene_name DDX11L1; transcript_type processed_transcript; transcript_status KNOWN; transcript_name DDX11L1-002; level 2; tag basic; transcript_support_level 1; havana_gene OTTHUMG00000000961.2; havana_transcript OTTHUMT00000362751.1;", 
"gene_id ENSG00000223972.5; transcript_id ENST00000456328.2; gene_type transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene; gene_status KNOWN; gene_name DDX11L1; transcript_type processed_transcript; transcript_status KNOWN; transcript_name DDX11L1-002; exon_number 1; exon_id ENSE00002234944.1; level 2; tag basic; transcript_support_level 1; havana_gene OTTHUMG00000000961.2; havana_transcript OTTHUMT00000362751.1;", 
"gene_id ENSG00000223972.5; transcript_id ENST00000456328.2; gene_type transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene; gene_status KNOWN; gene_name DDX11L1; transcript_type processed_transcript; transcript_status KNOWN; transcript_name DDX11L1-002; exon_number 2; exon_id ENSE00003582793.1; level 2; tag basic; transcript_support_level 1; havana_gene OTTHUMG00000000961.2; havana_transcript OTTHUMT00000362751.1;", 
"gene_id ENSG00000223972.5; transcript_id ENST00000456328.2; gene_type transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene; gene_status KNOWN; gene_name DDX11L1; transcript_type processed_transcript; transcript_status KNOWN; transcript_name DDX11L1-002; exon_number 3; exon_id ENSE00002312635.1; level 2; tag basic; transcript_support_level 1; havana_gene OTTHUMG00000000961.2; havana_transcript OTTHUMT00000362751.1;", 
"gene_id ENSG00000223972.5; transcript_id ENST00000450305.2; gene_type transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene; gene_status KNOWN; gene_name DDX11L1; transcript_type transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene; transcript_status KNOWN; transcript_name DDX11L1-001; level 2; ont PGO:0000005; ont PGO:0000019; tag basic; transcript_support_level NA; havana_gene OTTHUMG00000000961.2; havana_transcript OTTHUMT00000002844.2;"
)), .Names = c("Chromosome", "AnnotSource", "FeatureType", "Start", 
"Stop", "Score", "Strand", "GenomicPhase", "AdditionalInfo"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Your data is not clear. The `gene_id` it the name of the column or what? could you please provide a `dput` of your data?

Comment: Hey SabDeM. I added an example of what my data looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regexp and a capturing group to select what is after `gene_id` between quotation marks. 
For example, using the data you posted:

```
sub('.*gene_id ([^;]*).*',"\\1",og$AdditionalInfo)
sub('.*gene_type ([^;]*).*',"\\1",og$AdditionalInfo)
```

Output:

```
#[1] "ENSG00000223972.5"
#[1] "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"
```

You can also use `str_match` from `library(stringr)` to get `NA`s if there are no matches:

```
str_match(og$AdditionalInfo,".*transcript_id ([^;]*).*")[,2]
```

Output

```
#[1] NA                  "ENST00000456328.2" "ENST00000456328.2" "ENST00000456328.2"
#[5] "ENST00000456328.2" "ENST00000450305.2"
```

Comment: Thanks NicE. I tried the code $sub('.*gene_id "([^"]*)".*', "\\1", og$AdditonalInfo) and got the following error: character(0). Any idea what is off? Thanks for your help, I am an infant when it comes to regexes.

Comment: Can you post `dput(head(og))`, it's easier to import in R to do some testing and see if I get the same error

Comment: I just realized that the values to the keys aren't in quotes. I posted an update about my data above.

Comment: Just added the dput output above. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I edited the regexp, also, an i was missing in additional, that was the issue

Comment: As an offshoot of this question and since you're a regex master, any idea what I would do to put "NA" values if the pattern we are searching for is not matched? So if there is no "gene_id" or "transcript_type" match found in the AdditionalInfo column, I'd like to output "NA". You can see an example of this in the first row of my data above, where the AdditionalInfo column does not have the value "transcript_id". @NicE

Comment: you can use `str_match` from `library(stringr)`, I added it to the answer

Comment: You're awesome. Thanks again! @NicE